# ffmpeg android applying multiple filters in string array commands causes error

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

```
String[] command = {"-y",
            "-i",
            selectedVideoPath,
            "-vf",
            "hue=s=0",
            "scale=-1:'min(ih,720)'",
            "-vcodec",
            "mpeg4",
            "-ss",
            startMs,
            "-to",
            endMs,
            "-preset",
            "ultrafast",
            "-strict",
            "experimental",
            getAppPath(context) + fileName};
```

I am using above command in FFMPEG.execute() but its give error in Logcat:

Unable to find a suitable output format for 'scale=-1:'min(ih,720)''
scale=-1:'min(ih,720)': Invalid argument

So may be there is different technique to execute multiple filters command which I want know.

Note: selectedVideoPath and getAppPath(context) + fileName is source video path and destination video path with file name proper.

Comment: Pass all filters in one string: `"hue=s=0,scale=-1:'min(ih,720)'"`

Comment: Yup I found early. Thanks bro.